# Magento asking users to enable cookies

Tags: admin, cookie

Magento 1.9 CE running on LAMP stack.

Users land on site initially and they are getting Magento's "please enable use of cookies" page. They refresh and it is gone. I confirmed this behavior for Chrome and Safari.

Some are saying this is the solution to prevent it: Go to System –> Configuration –> General –> Web –> Session Cookie Management –> Cookie Lifetime = 5400

However my cookie lifetime was already set much higher than that and if you refresh even once the cookie is gone - changing cookie lifetime is not the fix.

I know how to turn it off: Go to System –> Configuration –> General –> Web –> Browser Capabilities Detection –> Redirect to CMS-page if cookies are disabled = No

But I'm most interested in what is actually causing it.

Comment: Is this a public or a local install?

Comment: Public install.

Comment: Have you tested saving your sessions to the DB instead of files?

Comment: No but I will. Doesn't that imply that there might be an issue writing sessions to the server?

Comment: I've edited my answer with new things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check if time (date and timezone as well) are set correctly on your server.
2. Check if Base URL of your installation is set correctly at `System > Configuration > Web`
3. Check if your sessions can be saved on filesystem or in DB. Open *app/etc/local.xml* file and look for <sessions> section, it is either set to `files` or `db`. Make sure that files can be written under `var/session` or in database and there is enough disk space or inodes.
4. If you use any third-party caching extension (turpentine or FPC or cache extensions that utilize varnish etc.), try disabling these extensions. To completely disable extension edit its XML config in *app/etc/modules/Extension.xml* and change <active> tag to *false*.

Answer (score 1):

You  can use this free extension it can help you easily

```
https://www.webinse.com/magento2-cookie-alert
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a localsetup then you can try out this:

[enable cookies issue in chrome and safari](http://www.jimcode.org/2011/04/magento-enable-cookies-displayed-cookies-enabled/)

This solved my problem also i was facing an issue with admin login in chrome, this solved it too. You won't have to do anything else.